# Swift URLSession prevent redirect

Tags: swift, urlsession

I have a client code for authentication to server ( server implemented so that on success I receive a Redirect url) and want to check whether the status code is 302 or not. However the request is automatically redirected and the response is 200. so the question is how to prevent auto-redirection?

```
let params = ["username":LoginField.text, "password":PassField.text] as! Dictionary<String, String>

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: NSLocalizedString("url_login", comment: ""))!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 302 {

                    result=1;

                }else{
                    result=0;
                }
            }
            semaphore.signal() 
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign a delegate to the URLSession in your controller or class, and implement the function below. source [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontaskdelegate/1411626-urlsession?language=objc) and ensure ULRSession is not a background one.

```
extension YourControllerOrClass: NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
    task: NSURLSessionTask,
    willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse,
    newRequest request: NSURLRequest,
    completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {
    // Stops the redirection, and returns (internally) the response body.
    completionHandler(nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to assign a delegate to your `URLSession`. Upon redirection, the method `URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:` will be called. Here, you can do your checks etc.

For more details, see the Apple documentation [Life Cycle of a URL Session](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html)

Comment: it's my first day working with Swift , may I ask you to make an example?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Alamofire this will work

```
 let delegate = Alamofire.SessionManager.default.delegate

        delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { (session, task, response, request) -> URLRequest? in

            return nil
        }
```